# Form Multiselect has particular option selected

Tags: jquery, html

I have a multiselect in my form and I want to display a text box 'specify other' when 'other' is selected in the multiselect, either by itself, or selected with something else.

This is what I have come up with, just wondering if there would be a quicker way without the 'for' loop, using jQuery somehow?

**HTML**

```
<div>
<select size="4" id='travel' name="Travel" multiple='multiple'>
    <option value="Air">Air</option>
    <option value="Sea">Sea</option>
    <option value="Train">Train</option>
    <option value="Car">Car</option>
    <option value="Bus">Bus</option>
    <option value="Animal">Animal</option>
    <option value="Walking">Walking</option>
    <option value="Other">Other</option>
</select>
</div>
<div id="otherTravel" class="clear">
    <p>Specifiy Other 
    <input type="text" name="otherTravel"/>
    </p>
</div>
```

**jQuery**

```
$('#travel').change(function() {
var $selectionArray = $(this).val();
for (var i = 0; i < $selectionArray.length; i++) {
    if ($selectionArray[i] == 'Other') {
    $('#otherTravel').removeClass('clear');
    }
    else {
    $('#otherTravel').addClass('clear');
    }
}        
});
```

**CSS**

```
.clear {
    display: none;
```

Comment: What do you mean by "quicker"?

Comment: quicker to code. I should have specified that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply use [indexOf](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) to see if the array hold the "Other"-value:

```
$('#travel').change(function() {
  var selectionArray = $(this).val();
  if (selectionArray.indexOf("Other") > -1) {
    $('#otherTravel').removeClass('clear');
  } else {
    $('#otherTravel').addClass('clear');
  }
});
```

Comment: this works well and I understand this code better than the other answers. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

```js
$('#travel').change(function() {
  console.log($('option[value=Other]', this).is(':selected'))
  $('option[value=Other]', this).is(':selected') ? $('#otherTravel').removeClass('clear') : $('#otherTravel').addClass('clear');


});
```

```css
.clear {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <select size="4" id='travel' name="Travel" multiple='multiple'>
    <option value="Air">Air</option>
    <option value="Sea">Sea</option>
    <option value="Train">Train</option>
    <option value="Car">Car</option>
    <option value="Bus">Bus</option>
    <option value="Animal">Animal</option>
    <option value="Walking">Walking</option>
    <option value="Other">Other</option>
  </select>
</div>
<div id="otherTravel" class="clear">
  <p>Specifiy Other
    <input type="text" name="otherTravel" />
  </p>
</div>
```

1. use attr selector combine with selector selected
2. based on number value add or remove class

Comment: Thanks for the solution. Do you mind elaborating what this means though:
$('option[value=Other]', this).is(':selected') ? $('#otherTravel').removeClass('clear') : $('#otherTravel').addClass('clear');

Comment: it means if the option with value `Other` is selected remove class clear from `#otherTravel` else add class

Comment: I get that part, but in particular the ? in that line, I have never seen it used before. Mind you I've only been using jQuery for a few weeks now.

Comment: it is ternary operator works just like if else . ? -> if : -> else

Answer (score 0):

You can replace looping to find in the "Other" option is selected or not by:

jQuery has a utility function for this:

```
$.inArray(value, array)
```

> Returns index of value in array. Returns -1 if array does not contain
>   value.